# How do I dump PROJ EPSG database to PROJ4JS-compatible PROJ strings?

Tags: proj, epsg, pyproj

I would like to know how I could dump the entire current/latest PROJ database of EPSG codes to PROJ4JS-compatible strings?

I have interrogated the proj.db using DBeaver and found that most of what I want is stored in the geographic and projected coordinate system tables. However, the ERD for those tables reveals that they link into other tables to pull many attributes.

The format of the proj4js strings (and thus, the desired output) is like the below:

`"EPSG:3819":"+proj=longlat +ellps=bessel +towgs84=595.48,121.69,515.35,4.115,-2.9383,0.853,-3.408 +no_defs"`

PROJ4JS Source:
https://github.com/stevage/epsg/blob/master/crs-defs.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to using Python, `pyproj` has a [`pyproj.database.query_crs_info()`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/database.html#pyproj.database.query_crs_info) method to return all of the codes.  `CRS` objects could then be built and exported to proj4 strings:

```
import json
import pyproj

crs_list = pyproj.database.query_crs_info()
crs_dict = {}

for info in crs_list:
    crs = pyproj.CRS.from_authority(info.auth_name, info.code)
    crs_dict[f'{info.auth_name}:{info.code}'] = crs.to_proj4()

print(json.dumps(crs_dict))
```

Comment: Wonderful answer! Thank you so much! I had to compile pyproj on Alpine, but otherwise, absolutely simple, straight-forward, and very useful!

Comment: Is there a way to include the towgs84 attribute as well?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about the towgs84 part

Comment: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/crs/coordinate_operation.html?highlight=towgs84#pyproj.crs.CoordinateOperation.towgs84

Does this seem to be the correct thing? I'm not sure how/where I'd implement this in the script you created above.

Comment: I don't think so, that looks like it represents a transformation as defined in the registry.  But I'm kind of out of my element at this point.  From what I can glean googling, it's recommended to exclude `towgs84` from the string and let proj choose an appropriate datum transformation at the time of use.  I might open a new question about that so someone more knowledgeable could answer

Comment: I opened a new question given your guidance:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403626/how-do-i-dump-towgs84-conversions-for-proj-strings

Comment: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/v1.9.6rel/pyproj-module.html

Given a working compile of pyproj v1.9.6rel and proj v5.2.0, is there a way to modify the script above to give the proper output, with the towgs84 string?

Comment: Not that I can see, that old version looks to be missing the pieces we need