# How do I dump towgs84 conversions for PROJ strings?

Tags: proj, pyproj

Building off of the awesome answer by mikewatt here:
[How do I dump PROJ EPSG database to PROJ4JS-compatible PROJ strings?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403432/how-do-i-dump-proj-epsg-database-to-proj4js-compatible-proj-strings)

How would one dump the towgs84 conversion from the PROJ database for a given EPSG value to be included in the output of the PROJ4JS compatible PROJ string?

Comment: Just as a note: In PROJ6 and later the `+towgs84` and `+datum` tags are deprecated, ultimately not allowing datum transformations using PROJ4 strings. Just something to keep in mind, but I guess there doesn't yet exist a JS package taking advantage of PROJ6

Comment: JonasV, so if my understanding is correct, this is not currently possible using PROJ8 and PROJ4JS together at all?

Deprecated could mean no longer recommended/marked for eventual removal, or it could mean already disabled in the codebase... I'm unclear here what the status is.

Comment: In that case it is already removed. However that doesn't mean that there can't exist a way to convert the PROJ6+ proj.db EPSG entries to corresponding +datum and +towgs84 entries. I am just not aware of one

Comment: JonasV, can you add that as an answer so I can accept it? I think that's about the state of things at the moment.